# iOS crash in WebCore::StorageMap::key(unsigned int)

Tags: javascript, ios

I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes in a WebThread, while my app is trying to process some javascript on a page startup.  The javascript is long and involved and is probably what's bringing this down. The only hint is that the call stack says it's happening in WebCore::StorageMap::key(unsigned int).  Can't debug it in the web debugger because it crashes on page startup so I never get to a point where the page can be selected in the developer menu.  Has anyone seen an error like this, or have a good way to track this down?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this issue? I'm dealing with the same in an app I'm working on now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally figured out what was wrong.  There were two pages - both used a third party Javascript library.  When you ran either of them, it was fine.  It was only after you ran one after the other where the second one crashed.  The reason was although they were running the same library, they were running different versions of the same library, which stayed resident in cache.  When the second page tried to run the library of the first page (because it was still in cache) it crashed.